# Predecessors and Successors of regular silting objects in bounded derived categories of wild hereditary algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, derived-categories, quivers, wild-representation-type

Let $\Lambda$ be a wild hereditary algebra and let $T$ be one of its regular silting objects (i.e. all indecomposable direct summands of $T$ are shifts of indecomposable regular modules). What do we know about predecessors and successors of $T$ in the silting quiver of $D^b(\Lambda)$? In particular can we have shifts of $\Lambda$ as predecessors or successors of $T$?